# RxJava combine Observable with another optional Observable with timeout

Tags: java, timeout, rx-java

Asume we have two observables `A` and `B`. `A` publishes a result certainly, while the result from `B` might not be published at all (timeout).

The question is how to map the result from `A` and `B` if `B` returns within a timeframe, otherwise just return the result from `A`.

```
Observable<DatabaseObject> A = getDatabaseElement();
Observable<NetworkObject> B = restApi.getElement();
```

Map example:

```
map((databaseObject, networkObject) => {
  databaseObject.setData(networkObject);
  return databaseObject;
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to timeout `B` observable use `take` operator with time argument:

```
B.take(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

In order to receive either `A` or `B` (if `B` is ready within timeout) use `concatWith`:

```
A.concatWith(B.take(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
    .takeLast(1)
```

In case you wish to combine `A` and `B` (optionally enrich `A` with `B`):

```
A.concatWith(B.take(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
    .reduce((a, b) -> a.setData(b))
```

In case `A` and `B` are of different types (optionally enrich `A` with `B`):

```
Observable.combineLatest(
    A,
    B.take(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).defaultIfEmpty(stubB)),
    (a, b) -> { if (b != stubB) a.setData(b); }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a different approach here .. There is an operator designed exactly for the behavior you described. Take a look at `.timeout(long time, TimeUnits units, Observable backupObservable)` which instructs a stream to switch from the original observable (in your case B, the network request I assume) to the backup A observable when there are no other items in the original stream for the specified amount of time.

Comment: This is not the usecase I need. I always want to return `A`s result, but optionally enrich it with data from `B`.